# Оставить [android-shared-preferences] или [sharedpreferences]?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть [android-shared-preferences](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-shared-preferences) (84 вопроса) и [sharedpreferences](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharedpreferences) (43 вопроса).

Зачастую вместе. [sharedpreferences без android-shared-preferences](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharedpreferences+-android-shared-preferences) всего в 17 вопросах.

На en SO [sharedpreferences](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharedpreferences) только есть. Хотя sharedpreferences употребляется всегда в контексте Android, но [android-shared-preferences](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-shared-preferences) кажется более логичной и структурированной меткой.

Что оставляем?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Делаем основной [android-shared-preferences](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-shared-preferences), а [sharedpreferences](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharedpreferences) синонимизируем к ней. Можно также прям в метке проголосовать за синоним https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/android-shared-preferences/synonyms

Comment: Ага, можно: если хватит рейтинга по ней.

Comment: @AK ну да, только те, кто в теме, могут проголосовать за синонимизацию)

Answer (score -3):

Делаем основной [sharedpreferences](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharedpreferences), а [android-shared-preferences](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-shared-preferences) синонимизируем к ней.